# Receiving same message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm running the sample gcm-demo-client provided in the sdk (extras/google/gcm/samples/)
and keep receiving the key1="From GCM: you got message!" from the received Intent,
even when I post different values.

For example, when I post the following body

```
{
    "data":{"key1":"value1","message":"this text will be seen in the notification bar!!"},
    "registration_ids":["$GCM_REGISTRATION_ID"]
}
```

I received the response with always the same message_id

```
{
    "multicast_id":4767008207494821680,
    "success":1,"failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":1,
    "results":[{"registration_id":"APA91bH7p....f1tT65n3A","message_id":"0:1343892969659984%921c249af9fd7ecd"}]
}
```

What did I miss in the API? how can I make my message unique?
Thanks for your help
Fabrice

Answer (score 3):

This is because in the GCMIntentService it sends the same message each time.You should change the following method in the GCMIntentService.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

Instead of

```
String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
```

you should get data from the intent shown below

```
String message = intent.getExtra("message");
```

For more information read Handling Received Data part [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html).